# parse to get all installations

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to get all installtions from parse using rest api

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <app_id_key>" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: <master_key>" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/installations
```

But why I only get 100 installations?  How can I get all my installtions?

THanks

Comment: Most people get confused with using the REST-API-Key instead of the Master-Key so it looks good, and the docs specifically state : Without any URL parameters, a GET request simply lists installations. You might have to narrow it down with users or specifically query a global channel that everyone registers on applicationDidFinishLaunching. It also may be a bug since the provided code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forcing a limit (there is still a 1000 result limit to queries for installations so your going to have to have to loop through the results if you have >1000) but hopefully by forcing a query limit it will result in the minimum you explicitly set. Also try doing it through cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.limit(1000);
query.find(function(results) {

});
```